# Wordpress Query based on Checkbox Value

Tags: wordpress, checkbox

I'm trying to query my custom post type of "projects" and return all posts that have the "custom_featured" checkbox checked on. This is my current query, however it's not returning anything although I have several posts with that checkbox checked.

```
$args = array(
     'post_type' => 'projects',
     'meta_query' => array(
                         array( 
                              'key' => 'custom_featured',
                              'value' => 'true',
                              'compare' => '='
                              )
                        )
        );
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { 
          while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                <h1><?php the_title();  ?> </h1>
            </a>                                                   
          <?php endwhile; 
          }

          wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: your query is working to me

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out. The 'value' should be "on" and not "true"

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code, if you are saving text values in the database from checkbox

```
'meta_query' => array(
                         array( 
                              'key' => 'custom_field_key',
                              'value' =>'custom_field_value',
                              'compare' => 'LIKE'
                              )
```

Comment: Please explain your answer more. So everyone understands, why your solution is the correct one.

Comment: this wp query is equivalent to following Sql query  SELECT * from wp_post_meta where value IN ( value1,value2 ) you can check it by printing the wp query array.

Comment: Linus 52  if you are saving text value from form the checkbox then use the following code  (
    'key' =>'services',
    'value' =>$company_service,
    'compare'=>'LIKE'
   );  it will work perfect for you.

Comment: Just edit your answer, I did not ask the question :-) it is more for the public, so they understand why they should try your answer.